# django save data once in a day to file after first script run

Tags: python, django

I'm a newbie in django. I'm providing some parsed content on a page from data, which was loaded from another web source via api. So, I'm wondering if there a way to load data one time in a day and then save it to a file, so my program will parse that data from a file for the rest of that day, not via api service? Where should I look for?

Comment: Save the data to the database with your Django model... and read data from it with a queryset.

Comment: Or just use the cache framework https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/cache/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a cron job that runs each day and fetches the data you need then saves it to a file on your machine (or better yet, to your database). [Django Cron](https://github.com/Tivix/django-cron) makes this pretty easy.

Answer (score 0):

As already stated, you could just write a script and use the system cron.  But since you are using django and python, you could as well go with https://django-cron.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html which allows you to schedule execution of code within django.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Django-celery to automatically execute any python function at a specific time or daily.
[Django-celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html)